# Suppose we fix $n$, does there always exist a prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 1$ modulo $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Whilst reading [this question](http://Suppose%20we%20fix%20%7B07d627e9-09a9-4eda-b1d0-55fed75c6102%7D,%20does%20there%20always%20exist%20a%20prime%20%7B5501aaa8-f2cc-495d-bc90-8e815da0a7f5%7D%20such%20that%20%7Be2fb139b-8095-42f5-914e-a551e21b8d97%7D%20modulo%20%7Bbd74e883-6dac-4cb6-8cfe-e95f1605c94a%7D?) I found this really nice explanation by Benjamin Peterson. However, I was wondering does there always exist a prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 1$ modulo $n$ for each $n$? I feel like this must follow from some famous result that I do not remember.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: That “famous result” that you're after is [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ahh I see, thank you so much!

Comment: Your link is not valid. Please search for answers before posing questions to help avoid avoid rampant duplication (a serious problem here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirichlet's prime number theorem states that *for any two positive coprime integers $a$ and $n$, there are infinitely many primes of the form $a + mn$, where $m$ is also a positive integer*. In this case, we just take $a=1$ and $n$ fixed. They are of course coprime, and therefore there exist not only one, but infinitely many primes congruent to $1$ mod $n$.

Edit: PS, as a nice fact, the statements "there exists one prime congruent to $a$ mod $n$" and "there exist infinitely many primes congruent to $a$ mod $n$" are, in fact, equivalent. Dirichlet's theorem can be formulated both ways.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).